# storage model for File_descriptor and Handle in Reactor pattern

Tags: c++, handle, reactor

I'm implementing the asynchronous pattern Reactor in C++, based on Epoll.
First, we will register file descriptor with the Reactor by calling the function

```
template<typename Handle>
void Reactor::register(int descriptor, Handle handle){
    //add this descriptor to epoll for monitoring
    //store this handle with the key is the descriptor
}
```

And then, the method hand_events, which run forever, is called

```
void Reactor::handle_events(){
    epoll_wait(..)
    for(event in events){
        //call the handle corresponding to the file descriptor return from epoll
        //event.data.fd ==> handle
        handle(...)
    }
}
```

My question how to organize the storage model in this situation: store Handle, and mapping between file descriptor and handle (is there any suitable Pattern for it)

Hope to see your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If all handlers have the same signature, then using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) in a [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) might be enough.

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::function<void(int)>> fdmap;
```

Then store like

```
fdmap[descriptor] = handle;
```

And simply call like

```
fdmap[event.data.fd](event.data.fd);
```

Of course, in event handler you want to make sure that the mapping actually contains the file descriptor.

---

You should be able to use different signatures if you use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) when calling your register function:

```
my_reactor.register(fd, std::bind(my_handler, _1, another_argument, a_third_argument));
```

Then when the event dispatcher calls your event handler function it would be the same as calling it with the first argument as the descriptor and the other arguments with the values you pass them in the `std::bind` call.

Comment: Pilebor: it's the problem. I just want to generalize my reactor pattern ==> I don't want to fix the signature ==> I used template for passing Handle. ==> Do you have any other idea or know how does boost::asio solve this problem?

Comment: @khanhhh89 You should be able to use `std::bind` when registering your event handler, as in my updated answer.

Comment: @khanhhh89 And Boost ASIO solves this by using function binding with either `std::bind` or `boost::bind`, but still with a somewhat fixed signature. The handlers _must_ take at least _these_ arguments in _this_ order, but with the magic of `bind` they can take more if needed.

Comment: thanks for your thoughtful answer. But with this kinds of passed-in handlers (std::bind(handle, arg1, arg2..) ) ==> How to i store it in the map (or other storage methods)?

Comment: Just another question. Could you recommend me for some books or documents relating to this problem, or some design pattern for it. Hope to see your answer!

Comment: @khanhhh89 You can store it as a `std::function` object like in my answer, that should work okay. And when you call the function it will be called with the whatever extra arguments you passed to `std::bind`. And if you don't have the object in the standard library (pre C++11) then Boost have those as well.